# eclipse refactoring API delete folders

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring, eclipse-rcp

I am currently writing a delete refactoring (`DeleteParticipant`) for a customized eclipse IDE.

What I try to archieve is the following:

When the user deletes a file, my DeleteParticipant registers that and deletes several other files. If this causes some folders to become empty, this folders are also deleted by my DeleteParticipant. If this causes some parent folders to become empty, again, they are deleted by the participant.

To achieve that, I create a `DeleteResourceChange` for each file and store them in a `CompositeChange` object that is than returned from my `DeleteParticipant`.

**Example:**

[image]

**Problem:**

The deletion works fine. However, when I try to undo the changes eclipse shows me the following error message:

```
'Delete' cannot be undone. Reason: There is not enough information to restore 'gen'.
```

As far as I understand the problem, this is due to the fact that the undo logic first checks if reverting of each file is possible and complains that it cannot restore the `gen` folder in the currently not existing `services` folder.

Is there any way to hint eclipse that the undo is nevertheless consistent?

**Question:**

Comment: An alternative might be to mark resources you create which can be recreated as 'derived' (see `IResource.setDerived`). I think refactoring may not complain about derived resources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but the refactoring still complains about the missing parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that reverting a single delete containing multiple files is possible, while reverting multiple deletes containing nested files is not. Thus, to solve the issue, I wrote a small method that does the following:

1. Create a IDeleteResourceChange for every deletion and remember the new file count in each parent folder.
2. Check if one of the parents becomes empty: If so, remove the single file deletion changes and add one change for the parent folder. Also, if desired, enter recursion.